# How manage big data in MongoDb collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection called **data** which is the destination of all the documents sent from many devices each **n** seconds.

What is the **best practice to keep the collection alive** in production without documents overflow?

How could I "clean" the collection and save the content in another one? Is it the correct way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that you cannot overflow collection, everything should be fine just in one, but maybe you should consider sending documents to destination collection? I think that you are going to create big overhead if you want to rewrite documents to other collections

Comment: If I overflow documents limit for a collection? What should the best practice be?

Comment: I posted full answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot overflow, if you use sharding you have almost unlimited space.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sharding-Existing-Collection-Data-Size

Those are limits for single shard, and you have to start sharding before reaching them.

It depends on your architecture, however limit (in worst case) of 8.19200 exabytes (or 8,192,000 terabytes) is unreachable for most of even big data apps, if you multiply number of shard possible in replica set by max collection size in one of them.

See also:

[What is the max size of collection in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939587/what-is-the-max-size-of-collection-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb is a best database for storing large collection. You can do below steps for better performance.

- **Replication**

Replication means copying your data several times on a single server or multiple server. 
It provides a backup of your data every time when you insert data in your db.

**Embedded document**

Try to make your collection with refreences. It means that try to make refrences in your db.

Comment: I am not speaking about performance, but simply about real limits of documents in a collection. I already replicate and make use of references/indexes for the data design. I haven't problems about performance.