# Size limit for mongo DB collection , documents and database

Tags: mongodb, limit

I have been learning and working on MongoDB for the last few months, now I am really confused about the maximum size limit of 16 MB per document.
I just want to know that, is this 16 MB size limit applies to a single document inside the collection or this limit also applies to a single collection.

As I have a collection with hotel schema, where I will be adding more than 5,00,000 documents as hotel information.

I tried to find out the maximum limit per collection, but I didn't find some information. I really would appreciate some highlights here.

Comment: _" i am really confused about maximum size limit of 16mb per document. i just want to know that, is this 16 mb size limit applies to a single document inside collection or this limit also applies to a single collection."_ : See [Document size limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit).

Comment: [What is the max size of collection in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939587/what-is-the-max-size-of-collection-in-mongodb/33944255)

Answer (score 5):

Currently, that is until V5.0 of MongoDB, [16MB is the size limit of a single bson document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) in MongoDB.

The number of documents per collection [is unlimited](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Maximum-Number-of-Documents-in-a-Capped-Collection) but if needed a limit can be manually set.

If larger documents or files need to be stored, MongoDB offers the GridFS mechanism that can support larger files.

Comment: Is there a Mongo best practice on number of documents per collction, ie. avoid having more than 1 million documents per collection?

Comment: MongoDB provides options to handle very large number of documents.  For instance if you have too many documents, you should consider sharding. While not a best practice, this answer may also help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320907/mongodb-billions-of-documents-in-a-collection